# Blender Python: Print debugging text from functions

Tags: python, development

I'm looking for a simple text-print setup where I can see multiple text outputs (multiple lines of text), similar to writing to a text file while ending every statement with an end-of-line.

A simple global function, such as `PrintDebug(text)`, which any code in my project can execute to show progress and stages of execution. Honestly, I expected the standard `print()` to do this. Where does `print()` print to?

Is there any built-in functionality to do this, or possibly a simple way to set this up?

Comment: Where do you want the output to appear? `print()` works, the output goes to stdout. Your terminal, console, command line will display the text, if you started Blender from it.

Comment: Preferrably into one of the Blender windows if possible, but any accessible area would be great, as long as I can see all of the lines that got printed. I start Blender from a shortcut on the desktop, and the console window disappears after Blender starts. I've never tried to execute from a console. Will try that when I get home, thanks.

Comment: If you're on Windows then you can toggle the console through *Window > Toggle System Console* in Blender.

Comment: This helped me tremendously. There are many errors shown in here that never make it to the info window in Blender. It explains a lot of missing details. I was able to resolve an issue in a few minutes that I face palmed over for 3 hours yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bpy.ops.wm.console_toggle()` to display the console, and then you can print using the `print()` method.